# More elegant way to achieve margins around UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to implement a number of views for the app, where content is based on a `UITableView` which should have left/right/top margins towards parent (`UIView`).

Currently I have to manually create constraints in the storyboard. Is there a way to achieve it programmatically?

[image: Prototype]

Answer (score 0):

what about...

```
@interface CustomViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation CustomTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.tableView = [UITableView new];
  self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

  NSDictionary *views = @{@"topLayoutGuide": self.topLayoutGuide, @"tableView": self.tableView};
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[tableView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topLayoutGuide]-20-[tableView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}

@end
```

Comment: For the vertical constraints I would use content insets. This prevents the cells from "magically disappearing" when you scroll the tableview up or down.